# Is there any way to restrict CDN calls in web pages multiple times?

Tags: html, reactjs, jsx, cdn, jsfiddle

I am building a react project in jsFiddle, i have include the CDN of react library such as "react.development.js" ,"babel.min.js", now the project is working fine, but every time I make any change and rerun the code it recall the all React and JSX library CDN as shown in the below image in the network tab

[image]

Is there any way to not to call these CDN libraries multiple times, and store it somewhere in browser or any place to avoid making extra network calls ?

Comment: If you want to use the cache, maybe don't tick "Disable Cache"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thankyou for giving the right direction, just one more question can this "Disable Cache" can be done by javascript ?